# Composing two Impulse Responses

Tags: convolution, impulse-response

Pardon my layperson understanding. My application is audio design.

What is the correct operation / algorithm to compose two impulse responses (`IRa`, `IRb`) into a third impulse response `IRc` such that it equals the response of running a signal through `IRa` then `IRb`?

Am I correct that since IRs represent the response to the delta function, that I can simply convolve `IRa` by `IRb` directly? i.e:

`IRc[n] = IRa[n] * IRb[n]`

Without needing to worry about deconvolving the output of the first IR convolution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

The impulse response of a cascade of two systems is the convolution of the individual Impulses responses. Convolution is commutative, so it doesn't matter in which order you convolve.

Impulse responses are ONLY defined for linear time invariant systems, so this will work for systems like equalizers or filters but NOT for things like dynamic processors or limiters.

Comment: Thank you kindly - it is nice to get confirmation of my understanding!